# how to create island with Displacement and don't separate whole mesh?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, displacement

[image]
[image]
I have island. I see it whole in camera - i shouldn't make separate a parts.
But I have displacement in this mesh, it looks enough on the mount, but bad looks on the ground.
How i can use soft gradient for displacement?
How can I make a soft gradient so that the displacement map only works on the mountain, but does not work on the ground?
[nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfF8E.png)

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/yKWmNVd3mvyBGg file if you need.

Answer (score 1):

Simple mix using Z position. First color I set as (0.5, 0.5, 0.5).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could e.g. use the object coordinate, ask for the z-value to be bigger than a certain value so that it only applies on the mountains or use another scale on the mountains like so:

[image]

then the result of the less than to mix color like this:

[image]

[image]

and if you wanna make it a bit more realistic and nicer, you add some noise to your "limit" so that the line is not so "good" to see like this:

[image]

then you get (i put the color here as well to the surface so that you can see the result better):

[image]

end result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks all. I resolve with b/w mask.